# Improve R script efficency

Tags: r, loops, time, performance

I am trying to match two very big data (nsar & crsp) sets. My code works quite well but needs a lot of time. My procedure works the following way:

1. Try match via ticker (thereby controlling that NAV (just a number) & date
   is the same)
2. Try match via exact fund name (controlling for NAV & date)
3. Try match by closest match: search first for same NAV & date --> take list and consider only those companies that are the closest match for both match measures --> take remaining entries and find closest match (but match distance is restricted).

Any suggestions how I could improve the efficiency of the code:

```
#Go through each nsar entry and try to match with crsp
trackchanges = sapply(seq_along(nsar$fund),function(x){

    #Define vars
    ticker = nsar$ticker[x]
    r_date = format(nsar$r_date[x], "%m%Y")
    nav1 = nsar$NAV_share[x]
    nav2 = nsar$NAV_sshare[x]
    searchbyname = 0

    if(nav1 == 0) nav1 = -99
    if(nav2 == 0) nav2 = -99

    ########## If ticker is available --> Merge via ticker and NAV
    if(is.na(ticker) == F)
    {

        #Look for same NAV, date and ticker
        found = which(crsp$nasdaq == ticker & crsp$caldt2 == r_date & (round(crsp$mnav,1) == round(nav1,1) | round(crsp$mnav,1) == round(nav2,1)))


        #If nothing found
        if(length(found) == 0)
        {

            #Mark that you should search by names
            searchbyname = 1

        } else { #ticker found 

                    #Record crsp_fundno and that match is found
            nsar$match[x] = 1 
            nsar$crsp_fundno[x] = crsp$crsp_fundno[found[1]] 
            assign("nsar",nsar,envir=.GlobalEnv)

            #Return: 1 --> Merged by ticker
            return(1)
        }

    } 

    ###########

    ########### No Ticker available or found --> Exact name matching
    if(is.na(ticker) == T | searchbyname == 1)
    {

        #Define vars
        name = tolower(nsar$fund[x])
        company = tolower(nsar$company[x])

        #Exact name, date and same NAV
        found = which(crsp$fund_name2 == name & crsp$caldt2 == r_date & (round(crsp$mnav,1) == round(nav1,1) | round(crsp$mnav,1) == round(nav2,1)))



        #If nothing found
        if(length(found) == 0)
        {

            #####Continue searching by closest match

                #First search for nav and date to get list of funds
                allfunds = which(crsp$caldt2 == r_date & (round(crsp$mnav,1) == round(nav1,1) | round(crsp$mnav,1) == round(nav2,1)))
                allfunds_companies = crsp$company[allfunds]

                #Check if anything found
                if(length(allfunds) == 0)
                {
                    #Return: 0 --> nothing found
                    return(0)
                }

                #Get best match by lev and substring measure for company
                levmatch = levenstheinMatch(company, allfunds_companies)
                submatch = substringMatch(company, allfunds_companies)

                allfunds = levmatch[levmatch %in% submatch]
                allfunds_names = crsp$fund_name2[allfunds]

                #Check if now anything found
                if(length(allfunds) == 0)
                {
                    #Mark match (5=Company not found)
                    nsar$match[x] = 5 

                    #Save globally
                    assign("nsar",nsar,envir=.GlobalEnv)

                    #Return: 5 --> Company not found
                    return(5)
                }


                #Get best match by all measures
                levmatch = levenstheinMatch(name, allfunds_names)
                submatch = substringMatch(name, allfunds_names)


                #Only accept if identical
                allfunds = levmatch[levmatch %in% submatch]
                allfunds_names = crsp$fund_name2[allfunds]


                if(length(allfunds) > 0)
                {
                    #Mark match (3=closest name matching)
                    nsar$match[x] = 3 

                    #Add crsp_fundno to nsar data
                    nsar$crsp_fundno[x] = crsp$crsp_fundno[allfunds[1]] 

                    #Save globally
                    assign("nsar",nsar,envir=.GlobalEnv)

                    #Return 3=closest name matching
                    return(3)

                } else {
                    #return 0 -> no match
                    return(0)
                }

            #####

        } else { #If exact name,date,nav found

            #Mark match (2=exact name matching)
            nsar$match[x] = 2 

            #Add crsp_fundno to nsar data
            nsar$crsp_fundno[x] = crsp$crsp_fundno[found[1]] 

            #Return 2=exact name matching
            return(2)
        }
    }   





})#End sapply
```

Thank you very much for any help!
Laurenz

Comment: can you post a simpler, reproducible example?

Comment: Some general advice. Write less comments, but cut your workflow up into functions. In that way you central loop would probably be around ten lines. This makes your main idea easy to grasp, and the details are contained in the functions.

Answer (score 2):

The script is too complicated to provide a complete answer, but the basic problem is in the first line

```
#Go through each nsar entry...
```

where you set out the problem in an iterative way. R works best with vectors.

**Hoist** the vectorizable components from the `sapply` that you start your calculations with. For instance, format the `r_date` *column*.

```
nsar$r_date_f <- format(nsar$r_date, "%m%Y")
```

This advice applies to lines buried deeper in your code, too, for example calculating the rounded crsp$mnav should be done just once on the entire column

```
crsp$mnav_r <- round(crsp$mnav, 1)
```

**Use R idioms** where appropriate, if "-99" represents a missing value, then use NA

```
nav1 <- nsar$NAV_share
nav1[nav1 == -99] <- NA
nasr$nav1 <- nav1
```

Code from other packages that you might use is more likely to treat NA correctly.

**Use well-established R functions** for more complex queries. This is tricky, but if I'm reading your code correctly your query about "same NAV, date, and ticker" could use `merge` to do the joins, assuming the columns have been created by vectorized operations earlier in the code, as

```
nasr1 <- nasr[!is.na(nasr$ticker), , drop=FALSE]
df0 <- merge(nasr1, crsp, 
             by.x = c("ticker", rdate_r", "nav1_r"),
             by.y = c("nasdaq", "caldt2", "mnav_r"))
```

This does not cover the "|" condition, so additional work would be needed. The plyr, data.table, and sqldf packages (among others) were developed in part to simplify these types of operations, so might be worth investigating as you get more comfortable with vectorized calculations.

It's hard to tell, but I think these three steps address the major challenges in your code.